# Why is uploading files to s3 via boto being throttled? And how can I make it faster?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-asyncio

#### Context

My objective is to move to s3, and I want to to that in a fast and robust way. I am trying to run the entire operation in memory and asynchronously (nice to have). Everything seems to work smooth; however, my primary concern is at the step where I upload (I use boto3) the files to S3. It seems that this step becomes very slow (or starts fast and then becomes very slow, as if it is throttled).

#### What I have tried to do

The function which I use to copy from postgres -> compress -> upload to s3 (happy to share full code if needed) looks like:

```py
async def sync_concurrently(query: str, pool: Pool, client: AioBaseClient, bucket: str):
    # Initiate COPY from s3 and log response
    query_data = await pg_copy(pool, query)

    # Gzip files async
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = await loop.run_in_executor(EXECUTOR, gzip_data, query_data)

    # Initiate upload to s3 and log response
    await upload_to_s3(client, bucket, future)
```

It's worth mentioning that I am using [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore) as  client to upload to s3 asynchronously, in which the aws upload uses the method `client.put_object` (documented [here](https://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)). Note that I have also used the native (non-async) boto3 `put_object` method (along other methods) but that results in the same issue.

#### What seems not to work as expected

The upload to s3 step takes a long time (about 20 minutes to upload 3 GB file) in comparison to using aws cli (takes a few seconds to upload a 3 GB file).

#### Other approaches I have tried

1. Changing file size: To my understanding, uploading data to s3 with `put_object` needs to be less than 5GBs, so I tried to upload with different file sizes (500 MB to 3 GB) but I still got the same behaviour
2. Not using aiobotocore and using aws boto3 (non async approach): The upload still takes a long time
3. Using aws boto3 `upload_file_obj` (documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)) with TransferConfig, similar to how it shown in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118024/11271048): The upload for files start fast and then suddenly throttles down to become very slow

#### Question

I noticed that when I use aws cli commands (like `aws s3 sync`) the upload to S3 is significantly (few minutes vs. an hour+) faster than using boto3 functions. Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I make my upload much faster or as fast as the aws cli?

I am happy to provide further details and/or improve my question if needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is aws CLI faster than using boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692483/is-aws-cli-faster-than-using-boto3)

Comment: Hi @FrancoPiccolo! Unfortunately not. I am trying to make it fast rather than understand why the cli is faster. I have updated my question to be more specific